# How do I configure munin to show separate graphs for virtual hosts on a single server?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, munin

I have a machine with several virtual hosts. How do I configure munin and munin-node to break up the network traffic/bandwidth by virtual host?

i.e. vhost1.example.com, vhost2.example.com where both are on the a machine with the same ip address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These [Munin-plugins](https://github.com/benlumley/munin-plugins) will help you to break up volume, access and errors in different graphs for your various virtual hosts. Take a look at the plugins for hints on how your access-log files must be named, where they are located, which files to include or which files to exclude.